# How automate a process than I must do in a web page

Tags: linux, web, automation

Hello everyone I'm here asking if someone can help me to know if there's a program to help me to make a repetitive process made it on web page developed in Java.

The process is:

(After login and I don't need automate this step) Select an input text then paste a value after that click on a button and then click in other button, but I need to know if exists some tool than can help me to do that withouth intervention.

Actually I'm working on Linux (Ubuntu) I made some searchs in google but wasn't satisfactory

Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: That sounds pretty awful; if you're not in charge of the java program (I hope you're not - if you are, expose that functionality in an API!) you could look at using selenium to  drive a browser to do what you're asking.

Comment: I haven't acess to code :(